# Eclipse PDT plugin gives me trouble

Tags: java, php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, ubuntu-11.04

Editor of PDT plugin jumbles the code and doesn't take responses in. I tried many things but didn't help at all. I was wondering what you guys are using to develop PHP applications for I am new to PHP. And I am a Java Programmer so I am more experience with Eclipse that is why I need to fix this issue.Below are few things I tried out

1. Reinstall PDT Plugin
2. Checked if Java editor works (it works perfectly)

I am out of solutions now and only think that I can think of is that Eclipse version is giving me trouble. I am using

> Version: Indigo Release
>
> Build id: 20110615-0604
>
> OS : Ubuntu 11.04
>
> PDT Version :  PHP Development Tools (PDT) All-In-One SDK    3.0.0.v20110516-1100-77

I am going to include few screenshots too. The screenshots were taken when I clicked in different places of the screen. And sometimes what I type is not displaying at all. Another thing I want to mention is that I also have Aptana plugin installed and the PHP is not working properly in it too. So PDT plugin might not necessarily be the cause for it. Will removing Aptana for PHP help me?
[image: Clicking around]
[image: Code jumbles up]
[image: Stuff disappears]
I have asked this question on AskUbuntu at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55185/eclipse-pdt-plugin-gives-me-trouble) I hope you don't mind the cross posting...

Comment: Just a side note, seems like PDT time is over: [http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/php_package.php](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/php_package.php). That's why you probably should look at netbeans (or phpstorm if you can spend 100$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is not be the answer you are looking for, but I never liked the PDT plugin (and Aptana stopped supporting their own PHP editor several years ago, which was far better.)

For editing PHP, I switched to NetBeans.  They have *excellent* PHP support, including refactoring, code completion with support for dynamic properties and methods, and more.  Plus, you can simply [download the PHP version of NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) and get started without much other configuration.

(I've since switched to [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) because I am developing Grails apps, but it is also really awesome for PHP.  However, the JetBrains products are not free.)

Comment: btw, Aptana brought the PHP support back into Aptana Studio 3. It's still a work in progress, and most of the previous features will be back in time.

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot, it looks like you are using the PDT editor, and not the Aptana Editor.
What you need to do is to change the File Association and the Content Types to have the Aptana PHP Editor handle the PHP files in your project (you can do so from the preferences).

Also, since you have both PDT and Aptana installed, you need to make sure that your project was created using the right wizard. That is... if you want to use PDT, create the project using the PDT PHP project wizard, and if you want to use Aptana - Use Aptana PHP project wizard.

Basically, what happens behind the scenes when you create a project is a setup for the project 'nature' and 'builders' that each plugin looks at in order to function correctly. So, although you can install both on the same eclipse environment, you better of sticking to one from the start.

Note: Since you have Aptana installed, you can also change the nature after the project was created. Go to the project properties (right click the project and select properties) and then click the 'Project Natures' item. If you want Aptana, select the items that display 'PHP' and 'Web' (those items should have icons next to them. make PHP as primary.)

If you want the PDT, select the item that show 'org.eclipse.php...' (if I'm not mistaken), and make it primary.

Hope that helps.